# INotifyPropertyChanged when PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have:

```
 <Page.Resources>  
    <data:PublishManager x:Key="pubManager"/>
 </Page.Resources>
```

then in my textBlock i used this:

```
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Canvas.ZIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SocialStatus, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource pubManager}}"></TextBlock>
```

my class PublishManager look like this:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _SocialStatus;
    public string SocialStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _SocialStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _SocialStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SocialStatus");
        }
    }
```

why when i write in my method code something like this it's don't work for me?

```
SocialStatus = "StackOverflow";
```

Why my page with TextBlock don't refresh content?

Comment: Does viewmodel declares `INotifyPropertyChanged` (I mean do you have `class PublishManager: INotifyPropertyChanged`)? I don't see errors otherwise, where is `TextBlock` located (maybe it can't reach `DataContext`)? Do you have binding errors in `Output` window?

Comment: @Sinatr i declares INotifyPropertyChanged,
binding work, in my TextBlock visible information, for example if it is declared in the constructor
 public PublishManager()
        {
            SocialStatus = "NIKITA";
        }
it's Binding is carried out, but if I override the property as nothing happens

Comment: *Override property*? Do you mean set value? How exactly are you setting the value?

Comment: @Sinatr when i write  public PublishManager()
        { SocialStatus = "NIKITA"; }
my textblock shows "NIKITA", but when I want to do in the method this
void someMethod(){ SocialStatus = "NIKITA"} it's don't work ;(

Comment: How do you run `someMethod`? Is it same (UI) thread as one used by bindings? Is it the same instance of viewmodel? Perhaps you are doing some silly mistake, but I can't see it because you didn't show enough code. Can you prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? You can [edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34748145/edit) to add clarifications to it (e.g. code is easier to read in there than in comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using static resource in your binding scenario. Static resources aren't monitored in case of property changes. Do you really need to use your `PublishManager` as page resource?

It would be better when an instance of `PublishManager` will be set as `DataContext`.

So firstly set `Page.DataContext`:

```
<Page.DataContext>  
    <data:PublishManager/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

And later bind to context property:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Canvas.ZIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SocialStatus}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the StaticResource here. They are used where resource value is not likely to change. Read below links:

[StaticResource](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jitendra1987/using-staticresources-in-wpf/)

[using StaticResource](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1142/resources-wpf-static-dynamic-difference)

if the value of **SocialStatus** is always going to be **StackOverflow** then declare the static property with that value and your binding should work. else you have to create an object of the class and give it as a datacontext to the view.

Or just create a datacontext when required

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Canvas.ZIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               Text="{Binding Path=SocialStatus, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
            <data:PublishManager/>
        </TextBlock.DataContext>
    </TextBlock>
```

this will work too.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

binding to a static source works. You just have to make sure data: maps to right namespace. As you did not provide the complete Xaml. you might want to check this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PublishManager.Page"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   xmlns:data="clr-namespace:namespace-to-code">
```

Although best practice is to use the DataContext to make it more reusable. Like the answer of Patryk provided.

Comment: Ok, but will then be NotifyPropertyChanged handled by a `TextBlock`?